# Sending data on the same php page by ajax (jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $var = $_POST['name'];
        echo $var;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
    <button id="submit">Button</button>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var foo = 'just_a_name';
                $.ajax({
                        url:'',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            'name':foo
                        },
                        success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert('success');
                            }
                });             
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Why won't this code work? I am not able to find out the error. All I am wanting to do here is send some data on the same PHP page.
When I click the Button button, alert('success') is displayed.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you forget the `<body>` tag? Is `url:''` supposed to query the same page?

Comment: try changing `url:''` to `url:'./'` but this will probably send it to the root folder of your website.

Comment: and what @A.L said might also be accountable.

Comment: Check to see exactly where the data is being POSTed using Firefox + Firebug or the like.

Comment: Keep in mind that `./` only works because this is the INDEX file, if it has a different name `./` wouldn't work.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have no `<body>`, and your `<button>` and `<script>` blocks are just floating in the document. The script block can go in the header, but the button cannot exist anywhere but inside a `<body>`.

Comment: @MarcB Sir, I already did that after A.L.'s comment, but only thing I see is the button itself.

Comment: The output of the Ajax should be in the "data" variable when inside the `success:` function, but you do nothing with it. Have you tried `alert(data)` instead of `alert('success')`? Also it's weird because as written, if it works, the Ajax is going to output `just_a_name` followed by all the HTML including the button.... Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @colmde Sir, I tried alert(data) and it showed me 'just_a_name' with the whole of the html code following it, but after clicking ok on the alert, the page still showed only the button.

Comment: Your Ajax is working perfectly so. It's the javascript after that that's not working the way you want. See my answer below for a more detailed answer as I'm not sure it'll fit in a comment.

Comment: The problem was that when an Ajax request is sent to a .php file, whatever response is supposed to come, comes in the data variable of success function (in case the request executed successfully). Hence it will not echo anything on the webpage unless assigned the 'data' to some html div, for example. I was new to it at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must works, put your php name file in the url and add the done() function to your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").click(function(){
   var foo = $(this).val();    
   $.ajax({
      url:'YourPhpNameFile.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
             'name':foo
            }, 
   }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert('success');
   });
});
</script>
```

or put

```
location.reload();
```

on the success() function.

Hope this helps you! Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

In following from my comment above:
First of all you need to put an `exit;` after the `echo $var;`, so it only displays that text and not the following HTML.

Then, you need a piece of code inside the `success:` function that will insert the `data` into your document.

something like

```
success: function(data) {
  $('html').before(data);
}
```

should do it.

That assumes you want the text displayed at the very top before even the opening `<html>` as your code suggests.

Comment: Sir, this doesn't seem to work. I guess, when the ajax request is executed, all the information which is contained in the 'data' variable of success, is not evidently sent to the page concerned, but it is just stored in the 'data'. It needs to be extracted from it. I don't understand If I made sense here, but I really had to change whole my design because of this conceptual problem. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying, which is why you need to put in that bit of JQuery from my answer - that is the line that takes the `data` variable and puts it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $var = $_POST['name'];
        echo $var;
    }
    $url = "http" . (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "s://" : "://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
    <button id="submit">Button</button>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var foo = 'just_a_name';
                $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo $url; ?>',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            'name':foo
                        },
                        success: function(data)
                            {
                                alert('success');
                            }
                });             
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, this doesn't seem to work. I guess, when the ajax request is executed, all the information which is contained in the 'data' variable of success, is not evidently sent to the page concerned, but it is just stored in the 'data'. It needs to be extracted from it. PS. I don't know if I made sense here.

Answer (score -1):

Only using PHP to submit the form and reload the page:

```
<?php
    // Displays only the variable 'name' if it is set
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $var = $_POST['name'];
        echo ('name=' . $var);
    }
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="ThisFileName.php" method="POST">
        <button name="name" value="hai">Button</button>
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

If you want to stay on the current page it may be easier to do so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <button id="submit" value="haihai">Button</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                // Your value from the button
                var value = $('#submit').val()          
                $('#result').text(value)
                alert('succes')
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: You said *Only using PHP*, but there is a jQuery function, that's unclear.